# cant use shuffle() on SplFixedArray() why so ? any other possible way?

Tags: php

cant shuffle *splfixedarray* why so ? what is the possible why to shuffle *splfixedarray*

```
<?php
    $cfix = new SplFixedArray(5);
    $cfix[0]=1;
    $cfix[1]=4;
    $cfix[2]=2;
    $cfix[3]=9;
    $cfix[4]=3;
    print_r($cfix);
    //cant shuffle splfixedarray why so ?
    shuffle($cfix);
    ?>
```

Comment: hm, I am wondering why you would shuffle a fixed array ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because `shuffle` expects an array as parameter.

> shuffle() expects parameter 1 to be array, object given..

Workaround using `toArray` and `fromArray`:

```
$cfix = new SplFixedArray(5);
$cfix[0]=1;
$cfix[1]=4;
$cfix[2]=2;
$cfix[3]=9;
$cfix[4]=3;
print_r($cfix);

$array = $cfix->toArray();

shuffle($array);

$cfix = SplFixedArray::fromArray($array);
print_r($cfix);
```

Answer (score 2):

I needed to shuffle a large fixed array (> 100,000,000 elements) so using the fixed array is necessary for a huge reduction in memory usage compared to an array.  A 100,000,000 element array of integers in PHP would require approximately 13.7 GB of memory where SplFixedArray is about 5.3 GB for the same list.

Since casting that large of an SplFixedArray to an array has an unreasonable memory cost (and defeats the purpose of using the fixed array in the first place), I wrote this function to randomize elements in place.

Compared to calling [`shuffle()`](http://php.net/shuffle) on an array, it's only marginally slower (0.48s vs. 0.32s using shuffle on an SplFixedArray vs array of 1,000,000 elements).

```
/**
 * Shuffle implementation for an SplFixedArray.  Like PHP's shuffle(array)
 * function, this randomizes the elements in the supplied array.
 *
 * @param \SplFixedArray $array  The array to shuffle in place
 * @param int $passes Number of passes over each element to randomize
 * @return bool true on success
 */
function shuffle_spl_fixed_array(\SplFixedArray &$array, $passes = 1)
{
    $size = $array->count();

    for ($pass = 0; $pass < $passes; ++$pass) {
        for ($idx = 0; $idx < $size; ++$idx) {
            $swap = mt_rand(0, $size - 1);
            $temp = $array[$swap];
            $array[$swap] = $array[$idx];
            $array[$idx]  = $temp;
        }
    }

    return true;
}
```

Increase the number of passes of make multiple calls depending on the amount of randomness needed, but I found one pass worked well enough for my purposes, especially if you can then pick from it at random.

Answer (score 0):

> cant shuffle splfixedarray why so ?

Because **`$cfix`** is an object in the form of an array. **`shuffle()`** works only on arrays, not on objects. The solution would be to cast the object to an array.

Try like this

```
<?php 
$cfix = new SplFixedArray(5); 
$cfix[0]=1; $cfix[1]=4; $cfix[2]=2; $cfix[3]=9; $cfix[4]=3; 

$cfix=(array)$cfix; //Casting the $cifx object to an array
shuffle($cfix);
print_r($cfix);
```